# Cache directory error message in R when applying the tbl_summary function from the gtsummary package

Tags: r, gtsummary

I want to use the tbl_summary function from the gtsummary package to summarize some baseline/demographic data. When trying to replicate the given example, I keep getting an error message regarding the cache directory and I cannot work out why I keep getting this message.

```r
library(gtsummary)


trial2 <- trial %>% select(trt, age, grade)
trial2 %>% tbl_summary()
#> Error in warning("Error using cache directory at '", cache_dir, "'. Using temp dir instead."): object 'cache_dir' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to stackoverflow! I can't replicate the error on my machine unfortunately. I did do some searching and it seems the issue is stemming from the sass package (gtsummary depends on the gt package, and gt depends on sass).

The error seems to be stemming from this line https://github.com/rstudio/sass/blob/593e61c41d0f952ebdaa8948f113ebf041ff905b/R/sass_cache.R#L189

While I don't know how to solve your problem, perhaps posting as issue on their GitHub page will get you the guidance to solve it.

Comment: Thank you @DanielD.Sjoberg for your reply. I'll post this on the GitHUb page to seek further guidance.